# Generate a random variable with an exponential distribution

Tags: matlab, statistics, random, exponential-distribution

In Matlab using the `rand` routine, how should I write the code to generate 500 samples from an exponential distribution, whose pdf is:

```
(1/mu)*exp(-x/mu); x>=0
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Have you read e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution?

Comment: http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/stats/exprnd.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you really have to do it using the `rand` function: exploit the property that the [minus logarithm of a normalized uniform RV](http://www.stat.wisc.edu/~larget/math496/random2.html) is a normalized exponential RV:

```
samples = -mu*log(rand(1,500));
```

Comment: you can use `reallog` in this context.

Answer (score 1):

Use `random` function.
For example to create a 4*6 matrix with mu=1.3 with an exponential distribution use:

```
random('Exponential',1.3,4,6)
```

or

```
random('exp',1.3,4,6)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have the Statistic toolbox you can simply use [`exprnd`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/exprnd.html) much like you use `rand`:

```
r = exprnd(mu);
```

where the size of `r` will be the size of the mean, `mu`, or

```
r = exprnd(mu,m,n);
```

where `mu` is a scalar mean, and `m` and `n` are the size of your desired output. If you type `edit exprnd`, you'll see that the code is virtually identical to that kindly provided by @LuisMendo. You might find the other functions related to the [exponential distribution](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/exponential-distribution.html) helpful to, such as [`exppdf`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/exppdf.html) and [`expcdf`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/expcdf.html). These are simple as well and implement basic equation that you can find in your textbook or on Wikipedia.